# Declare a function using a generic parameter

Tags: kotlin

I have these two functions:

```
fun displayTotalSelectedString(btn: ListItemButton, items: MutableList<String>?, resId: Int) {
    btn.text = if ((items == null) || (items.size == 0)) getString(resId) else getString(resId) + "  (" + items.size + ")"
}

fun displayTotalSelectedInt(btn: ListItemButton, items: MutableList<Int>?, resId: Int) {
    btn.text = if ((items == null) || (items.size == 0)) getString(resId) else getString(resId) + "  (" + items.size + ")"
}
```

They are almost identical except the second parameter in both functions. One takes a generic String while the other an Int.

Is there a way to create just a single function that would handle both generics. I tried `MutableList<Any>?` but that gets rejected.

Comment: did it not occur to you to read the docs? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
fun <T> displayTotalSelectedInt(btn: ListItemButton, items: 
    MutableList<T>?, resId: Int) {
    btn.text = if ((items == null) || (items.size == 0)) getString(resId) else getString(resId) + "  (" + items.size + ")"
}
```

Comment: Awesome. New to Kotlin, so it wasn't obvious.